# python regex fails to match whitespace in json

Tags: python, regex, json

I have a json file I'd like to clean up. I use a python dictionary to match a pattern and replace with another string. For example, I use a parse dictionary to replace the key with the value:

`parse_dict = {"\\r\\n\s*<!--\s*INTRODUCTION\s*-->\s*\\r\\n":""}`

My json look like this:

`[{"name": ["website1"], "description": ["<p>\r\n <!-- INTRODUCTION -->\r\n </p>", 
"<p>\r\n some text \r\n </p>"...`

I'd like to remove the `<p>\r\n <!-- INTRODUCTION -->\r\n </p>` part. But somehow the parse dictionary fails to match that string. Any idea why?

Moreover, I tried `{"<!-- INTRODUCTION -->":""}`, directly using space instead of `\s`, and it matches.

Also tried `{"\s*<!-- INTRODUCTION -->":""}`, didn't match.

Comment: Why clean it up _before_ parsing? Parse it, the you can directly modify the elements you don't like.

Comment: Can you show us exactly the code that you are using for matching?

Comment: This is exactly the code... I use the parse dictionary's key to match, the value to replace.

Comment: what do you mean by parse it first and modify later, @BryanOakley?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're doing, but it actually works:

```
>>> parse_dict = {"\\r\\n\s*<!--\s*INTRODUCTION\s*-->\s*\\r\\n":""}
>>> json = '[{"name": ["website1"], "description": ["<p>\r\n <!-- INTRODUCTION -->\r\n </p>", "<p>\r\n some text \r\n </p>"...'
>>> for pattern, replacement in parse_dict.items():
        json = re.sub(pattern, replacement, json)

>>> json
'[{"name": ["website1"], "description": ["<p> </p>", "<p>\r\n some text \r\n </p>"...'
```

Comment: It works because I copied and pasted from the json using a text editor when I wrote this question. This doesn't accurately reflect the actual json, because the text editor may have processed the json, and this website may have further processed the string I pasted. I'm suspecting that the json contains some whitespace character that's not a standard whitespace character. It could be an encoding issue.